# Prevent duplicate key error with orphanRemoval set to true when saving entities

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I've got the following tables/entities:

```
User (id, ...)
Ressource(id, ...)
UserAccess(id, user_id, ressource_id)
```

The connection between User and UserAccess is as follows:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<UserAccessEntity> userAccesses = new ArrayList<>();
```

Let's suppose there are already the following entries in the tables:

User:

```
| id |

| 1 |
```

UserAccess

```
| id | user_id | ressource_id |

| 1  | 1 | 1 |
```

What I do in my workflow is retrieving the User entities from the database, setting user accesses anew (they might change completely or some might be added or removed) and then saving the User entities.

In my test I retrieve  the User(id = 1) Entity and set UserAccesses exactly the same value as it is in the database.

It used to work but after I introduced a constraint on unique combination of user_id ressource_id in the UserAccess table, I get "duplicate key violates unique constraint"

Is there a way of not getting this error without deleting/merging the userAccesses first?

Comment: Your table setup seems odd for what you are mapping with hibernate. You shouldn't need `UserAccess` table. Instead add a `user_id` column to `Ressource` table and map off of that. And for uniqueness, you can make a composite primary key on user_id and resource_id

Comment: I cannot change the db setup.

Comment: No, not really. While some providers (EclipseLink) have flags you can set to perform deletes first, JPA does not guarantee order for how/when orphan removal clears out the de-referenced entities and when it finds and inserts the new ones. If you are going to attempt this, you must enforce ordering yourself by clearing the list, calling flush, then adding in the new entities unfortunately. Or merge the collection into the existing one.